# The stripe terminal connectiontoken has already been redeemed

Tags: xamarin.ios, stripe-payments

I'm integrating stripe terminal sdk into our app.

Currently, once the user is connected to the chip reader device, it will be connected for the lifetime of the app activity.

The only way to disconnect it and reconnect to another chip reader device is to kill the app and re-pair with that new device.

So here is my current process:

1. init the sdk via `setTokenProvider`, somewhere in the beginning
2. discover readers
3. connect to selected reader

Now below is the new process that im trying to implement:

1. init the sdk via `setTokenProvider`, somewhere in the beginning
2. discover readers
3. connect to selected reader
4. disconnect current reader
5. connect to a different reader. This is the part where it threw up the error `The stripe terminal connectiontoken has already been redeemed. Please generate a new one using v1/terminal/connection_token`

I can generate the new token any time i want, but how do i set it in the sdk? i have tried just calling the `setTokenProvider` the second time, but that of course crashed the app as it stated in the stripe doc that settokenprovider should only be called once.

So has anyone else ever tried to implement this process of giving the user the option of switching between devices without having to kill the app? any pointer would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by reading the doc on stripe's website... i know!

Turns out when we connect to a new device, the sdk calls the `fetchconnectiontoken` method automatically. So what I needed to do was grab a new token before connecting to the new device.